# Computer takes a long time to search for a wireless network that other devices can detect

Tags: wireless-networking

My Windows 10 laptop is currently connected to my home wireless network. However, when I turn off the Wi-Fi connection and turn it back on again, my computer can't sense the presence of my network. It normally takes 5-10 minutes of waiting before the wireless network shows up again in the list of available networks.

This is a consistent problem. The wireless signal is not the strongest, but it is strong enough that my other devices (Macbook, iPhone, iPad) are able to maintain a connection with the network and does not run into the current problem.

I'm not looking for a solution to my particular issue. Instead I'm trying to understand why this is behavior occurs and what my computer does when trying to scan for new wireless networks.

Comment: When asking a technical question, please provide plenty of technical detail. Which wireless chipset are you running on your Windows laptop? What channel is your AP on? Have you tried using a different wireless chipset under Windows 10 (maybe borrow a USB dongle or have a friend try his Windows 10 laptop or something)?

Answer (score 0):

Check for 3rd party wireless software that can be removed. i.e. Proset/wireless software(Intel) and then re-install your drivers as they will interfer with the management of your wireless chip set.